# Stimpack color and buff

Tags: starbound

I've found some stimpacks and I know that the red ones give health.

as far i saw green, blue, yellow, and red.

what are they doing?
are there more?

Comment: Yellow makes you glow, Green could be either energy or antidote. Blue no idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Stim Pack Status Effect**

```
Red Stim Pack       Regeneration
Blue Stim Pack      Jump Boost
Green Stim Pack     Speed Boost
Yellow Stim Pack    Glow
```

Source: [Here](http://starbound.wikia.com/wiki/Stim_Packs)